# PHP doesn't connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

I want to make a form that when a user types some input the program puts it in a database in a table. I'm using PDO to connect to the database but when i type something it doesn't do anything. Can you help me? What have i done wrong in the code? I have a seperate file for the code of PDO and i include it in the php file.
The PDO code:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=music', 'kat', 'msc');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

I have created the database in MySQL and a table inside called album. I want the user to type the name of the artist, a song and the number of the album and automatically save it in the table. My code in PHP:

```
<?php
require_once "pdo.php";  
$sql= "INSERT INTO album(name, song, number) VALUES ( :nm, :sn, :nb)";
echo("<pre>\n".$stmt."\n</pre>\n");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
':nm' => $_POST['name'],
':sn' => $_POST['song'],
':nb' => $_POST['number']));
}
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT name, song, number FROM album");
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

And the code for the form:

```
<form method="post">
<p>Name:
<input type="text" name="name" size="60"/></p>
<p>Song:
<input type="text" name="song"/></p>
<p>Number:
<input type="text" name="number"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Add">   
</form>
```

When the "Add" button is pressed i will do some input validation for the data like not null, integer number etc. but i haven't done it yet because i can't even get the simple part to work. I'm using xampp and MySQL works separately, my php file just doesn't do anything.
What am i missing?

Comment: Your form has no "action", so it never gets executed.

Comment: Voting as a typographical error.

Comment: what should i put in action that connects it to the database?

Comment: `<form method="post" action="your_php_file.php">`

Answer (score -1):

Thats sorted please follow this code :

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if( isset($_POST['postdata'])) { 

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "kat";
    $password = "msc";
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=music", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     
    $sql= "INSERT INTO album(name, song, number) VALUES ( :nm, :sn, :nb)";
    echo("<pre>\n".$stmt."\n</pre>\n");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':nm' => $_POST['name'],
    ':sn' => $_POST['song'],
    ':nb' => $_POST['number']));
    
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT name, song, number FROM album");
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($rows);


    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>



<form method="post">
<p>Name:
<input type="text" name="name" size="60"/></p>
<p>Song:
<input type="text" name="song"/></p>
<p>Number:
<input type="text" name="number"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="postdata">   
</form>
```

I did some changes to make it working

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can i have the connection to the database in a seperate file so that i can use it to other files without having to type it again in every file?

Comment: Let me send you

Comment: So when i create the separate file i just delete all these from my other file? Also i want the input to be printed as a list under the form and not at the beginning as an array. Do i put echo statements under the form with $name etc?

Comment: Please download that from here

http://webdevelopmentpunjab.com/stackoverflow/pdoconnection.zip

Comment: Also i want the input to be printed as a list under the form and not at the beginning as an array.

For this firstly you need to separate the array with foreach and yes you can do that at the last of the form element.

Put these lines at the last

 $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT name, song, number FROM album");
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($rows);

foreach($rows as $row)
{
   echo $row[0]->name;
}

Comment: I managed to make the list but the results aren't correct. It displays the last result i type over and over. What's wrong? What you told me didn't work so i tried: foreach($rows as $row) { echo $_POST['name']; ..... }.

Comment: Okay, I did that for you,
please download the new zip from here with updated code in pdo.php
have a look:

http://webdevelopmentpunjab.com/stackoverflow/pdoconnection_latest.zip

Hope this would help. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. One last thing, i want to have a login page that when a user enters the correct credentials it goes to the music page where he has to type the input for the database i already have but if he hasn't log in i want the die() function, but i want it to die even if he just tries to go to the music page without loging in. i have put: if (!$_GET['username'])  {    
     die("Name parameter missing"); in the music.php and it works if i try to go to the music page but when i type the correct credentials it still says Name parameter missing. How should i put the die function?

Comment: Hi,
You need to create session for login and at the music.php you need to check if user is logged in by if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { echo "Parameter is missing or please login to see this page"; }